# My android production release is active but I can't find my app in play store

Tags: android, google-play, release, production

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I recently released a production version of my app on the Google Play Store. After a 2-day review process, it was accepted and is now listed as active and available in the store. However, I'm facing a couple of issues:

Invisibility in Play Store Searches:

When I search for my app in the Play Store, it doesn't appear in the search results.
The app only becomes visible when I use the direct link provided by Google.

Oddly, when accessing the app through the direct link, it's labeled with **Beta interne** which is unexpected as this should be the production release.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is most properly wrong OR you are an internal tester.

Try to open the link from PC from browser on incognito mode.

Also, apps need sometime to be searchable on Google Play, they index a lot of apps so usually it takes some time to find the app from search.